# getInfo use in earthengine-api (Python)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

When I write the an algorithm in Google Earth Engine using JavaScript by using the Code Editor, it works fast. After thatif I use the `Map.addLayer()`， the result of algorithm can show in the map quickly.

However, after I translate the algorithm into the version of Python with the earthengine-api and I want to get some intermediate results, I need to use the `.getInfo()` function. According to the official tutorial, you shouldn't use `getInfo()` unless you absolutely need to. If you call `getInfo()` in your code, Earth Engine will open the container and tell you what's inside, but it will block the rest of your code until that's done. So this function will slow down my program.

How can I address this issue in Python?

Comment: Just don't get the intermediate results, unless you're happy with the associated penalty?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the Code Editor and you `print()` something, or `Map.addLayer()`, the request is sent asynchronously (allowing the rest of your code to continue running) and its answer is displayed whenever it comes back.  When you use `getInfo()`, it's synchronous — your code stops running until the answer is available.  If you don't need whatever you're calling `getInfo()` on to be local, then don't use it.  If the result must be local, then you should be prepared to wait for it, especially if it's a complex computation.

Comment: could you give me your email address？I want to communicate  with you more